# MLE vs. OLS Outputs Differ In R For AR(1) Time Series Model

Tags: r, time-series, maximum-likelihood, least-squares, autoregressive

I am trying to fit an AR(1) model to some data in R. I would expect the estimates from the OLS and MLE estimation procedures to be equal for both fits (as the function that needs to be maximised using both methods is the same when we assume the errors are normally distributed). However, I don't seem to understand why they differ.

In R, the function ar.ols fits an intercept term to the AR(1) model, but this can be set to zero so that the model being fitted has the same structure as when using the MLE method.

Based on this, I am trying to fit (as per the R documentation):
$$X_{t+1}-\mu=\phi (X_t-\mu)+\epsilon_t.$$

Some example code:

```
some_data<-c(60,43,67,50,56,42,50,65,68,43,65,34)/68   
ts_model_1 <- ar(some_data, order.max=1, method="mle")
ts_model_2 <- ar(some_data, order.max=1, method="ols", intercept=FALSE)
```

And some output:

```
Call:
ar(x = some_data, order.max = 1, method = "mle")

Coefficients:
      1  
-0.5443  

Call:
ar(x = some_data, order.max = 1, method = "ols", intercept = FALSE)

Coefficients:
      1  
-0.5803
```

As you can see the values for $\phi$ differ. But as the MLE and OLS methods should be invariant, this makes me question what is wrong here?

The documentation for ar and ar.ols are [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ar) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/ar.ols) respectively.

Comment: On second thoughts, my assumption of OLS being equivalent to MLE is true if the conditional likelihood function is used. I assume R must implement an unconditional likelihood function instead, where the estimation procedures may differ.

Comment: You may search the site for related questions; there have been a few similar ones before. Perhaps you will find one that has been answered.

Comment: @RichardHardy I had a look on the similar questions before posting and also had a thorough search beforehand. I suspect it may be that R uses unconditional MLE in its estimation procedure that causes the difference. I've tried to benchmark using Python and I get the same results using the ARIMA / SARIMAX functions and it seems SARIMAX at least uses unconditional MLE.